# How does an object's volume affect its gravitational pull?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, symmetry, planets

Two instances. An object is in front of two different planets with the same masses, but two different volumes. How does the gravitational pull vary from each planet? I am thinking with more given volume, the gravitational pull will be weakened slightly as a certain distance is approached because there is more planet gravity pulling from the edges of the planet and less gravity is concentrated at the center.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem

Comment: Is the object the same distance from the planets' centres?

Answer (score 1):

If the two planets have spherically symmetric mass distributions, then their gravitational forces on an exterior object depend only on their masses and not on their volumes.

Comment: Indeed ... which can be easily seen by *reading* the equation $F=Gm_1m_2/r^2$, which does NOT contain a volume term.

Comment: That equation is for point masses, which don’t have volumes. It is a nontrivial result that it also applies to spherically symmetric mass distributions.

Comment: But it DOES apply to spherically symmetric mass distributions, so my reasoning is still valid.

Comment: Obviously the OP did not know that that equation applied to extended objects, or he would not have asked the question.